# Delete netconn LWIP

Tags: c, client, freertos, lwip

I'm having trouble managing netconn if the remote server is unreachable, meaning releasing the resources of netconn_new when netconn is in the ERR_INPROGRESS state. In non-blocking mode, if I execute netconn_delete, I get an ERR_INPROGRESS error, and if I use netconn_close, I get the ERR_CONN error. If I'm in blocking mode, the task executing netconn_connect is indefinitely blocked, and it's impossible to release the resources from another task. These are the same errors as before.
How do you use netconn in this case? Thank you.

I try to use netconn in blocking and non blocking state. Otherwise netconn work well